# Laravel : How to get object in column with query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to display what kind of data I have described below, but I don't know the keywords.

For now, this is my data:

[image]

And this is the result I want:

[image]

This is, my controller:

```
$data = DB::table('tr_doctor_schedules as sch')
    ->select('sch.id as schedule_id','doctor_name','hospital_name','estimated_practice_time','day','from_time','until_time')
    ->join('mst_hospitals as hos', 'hos.id', '=', 'sch.hospital_id')
    ->join('mst_doctors as doc', 'doc.id', '=', 'sch.doctor_id')
    ->join('tr_doctor_schedule_details as dtl', 'dtl.doctor_schedule_id', '=', 'sch.id')
    ->where('sch.hospital_id', $hosId)
    ->where('sch.doctor_id', $docId)
    ->first();

if ($data) {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' =>'success',
        'data'    => $data
    ], 200);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'message' => 'Data not found.',
    ], 400);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you need to use `group_concat` for day column

Comment: why the from time is 8 not  9, and until time is 18 not 19 , is there a logic for it?

Comment: from line 9 to the end, no logic there, but I just added the response too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   $data = DB::table('tr_doctor_schedules as sch')
        ->selectRaw('sch.id as schedule_id,doctor_name,hospital_name,estimated_practice_time,GROUP_CONCAT(day) as day,from_time,until_time')
        ->join('mst_hospitals as hos', 'hos.id', '=', 'sch.hospital_id')
        ->join('mst_doctors as doc', 'doc.id', '=', 'sch.doctor_id')
        ->join('tr_doctor_schedule_details as dtl', 'dtl.doctor_schedule_id', '=', 'sch.id')
        ->where('sch.hospital_id', $hosId)
        ->where('sch.doctor_id', $docId)
        ->groupBy('sch.id')
        ->first();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its solved. In postgres i used array_agg()

Comment: yeah .. my pleasure